# Probability of Markov chain often returning to the initial state v2.0

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Suppose $a(t)$ is an irreducible aperiodic discrete time Markov chain with $n$ states, transition matrix $A = (p_{ij})_{0 \leq i,j < n}$ and initial state $0$. Suppose, $\alpha \in (0;1)$. How can I find $\lim_{t \to \infty}P(|\{0 \leq \tau \leq t| a(\tau) = 0\}| \leq \alpha t)^{\frac{1}{t}}$?

Suppose $\pi(x)$ is the stationary distribution of this Markov chain. Then $\frac{|\{0 \leq \tau \leq t| a(\tau) = 0\}|}{t}$ converges almost surely to $\pi(0)$, because of the Theorem C.1 from ["Markov Chains and Mixing Times" by David A. Levin](https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/mcmt2e.pdf), which states:

> Suppose $X$ is the set of all states of an irreducible aperiodic finite-state Markov chain $a(t)$, $\pi$ is the stationary distribution of $a(t)$ and $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is some arbitrary function. Then $\frac{\sum_{s=0}^t f(a(t))}{t}$ converges almost surely to $\sum_{x \in X}f(x)\pi(x)$.

From that we can conclude, that if $\pi(0) \leq \alpha$, then $\lim_{t \to \infty}P(|\{0 \leq \tau \leq t| a(\tau) = 0\}| \leq \alpha t)^{\frac{1}{t}} = 1$. However, this argument does not work for $\alpha < \pi(0)$. How can it be done here?

Comment: A am not sure what quantity you want to compute? What exactly is $|\{0\leqslant \tau \leqslant t\vert a(t)=0\}|$?

Comment: @Math1000 I read that as the number of times the chain is in state $0$ over the time interval from $0$ to $t$ inclusive, and I understand the quantity the OP wants to compute is $\ \lim_\limits{t \to \infty}P(|\{0 \leq \tau \leq t| a(\tau) = 0\}| \leq \alpha t)^{\frac{1}{t}}\ $ for values of $\ \alpha \ $ less than $\ \pi(0)\ $.  I strongly suspect that the limit will be $0$ in that case.

Comment: I don't see how $\frac1t\sum_{s=0}^t f(a(t))$ converging almost surely to $\sum_{x\in X}f(x)\pi(x)$ gives us a bound on the distribution of occupancy time in state $0$. Do we use $f(a(t)) = \mathsf 1_{\{0\}}(a(t))$?

Comment: @Math1000, yes.

Comment: So $$\frac1t\sum_{s=0}^t \mathsf 1_{\{0\}}(a(t)) \stackrel{t\to\infty}\longrightarrow \sum_{x\in S} \mathsf 1_{\{0\}}(x) \pi(x) = \pi(0)\ ?$$ Neat result.